# Access my Postgresql database inside a Kubernates pod from my computer with pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I installed a Postgresql database with Kubernetes into one of my pod. The communication works fine beetwen application in the other pods and my database and I can access it with those commands:

```
kubectl exec -it name_of_my_pod -n name_of_my_namespace -- "/bin/bash"
psql
```

I would like now to access the database with IntelliJ, pgAdmin or something like that. How can I do this?

*Secondary question: Is it really recommended to do it this way (postgres into a pod)? Or is better to have the database out of Kubernetes*?

Answer (score 2):

To access the database, you can expose the pgadmin tool via a Load-Balancer or Ingress controller. This is not always ideal from a security standpoint- as you are trusting the pgadmin tool to properly handle security. Another way to do this is to expose the pgadmin tool via cluster IP - or an internal IP address. This means, that those people outside of your clusters network, cannot access it. Then for you to access the tool, you would have to add a ssh/vpn tunnel or use kubernetes [port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) tool.

For deployment, [this](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/cetic/pgadmin) helm chart seems to be fairly reasonable, and you can control how you expose the admin utility.

Personally, if security is not of the upmost importance, I would expose pgadmin via an ingress controller. This would be the most convenient way to access the tool.

As for your second question, you can run postgress inside of a pod - but you need to make sure you have a persistent volume setup as the datastore location - as pods should be considered ephemeral. If you are struggling with how to start, I usually find Bitnami's offerings (free) a really good place to begin. [Here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql/#installing-the-chart) is the link to the helm chart for postgress SQL. With Bitnami's charts, make sure to set the passwords and accounts during the deployment process- otherwise the deployment will work the first time, but not if you have to redeploy - as the randomly generated passwords will change.

As a note, with some helm charts I use the `--dry-run` flag to get the raw yaml which I use to do a more standard kubernetes deployment. Make sure to set your helm options properly, and then add that flag.  This can be easier if you are just starting and are trying to customize something that does not have a built-in argument.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should have service object to make it accessable via ingress or nodePort.

For secound question: answer is not so clear and it depends on what you want achive.

As Ben said above, you have to make sure that you have peristent volume on which you can trust. As i know amazon could deliver some solutions but i dont konow if you want to store youre data into third party companies.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar kind of setup. PostgreSQL db pod is deployed in kubernetes cluster running in AWS cloud. And my pgAdmin is running in docker container in my local machine. Following are the steps that I performed to access this remote database from pgAdmin running in my local machine (Followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viuggqNLBcE)).

1 -> Modify the Service type of db from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort` as shown below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db

spec:
  selector:
    app: db
  ports:
    - name: dbport
      port: 5432
      nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
```

2-> Add new rule to security group of any node(EC2 Instance) of your Kubernetes cluster as shown below.

[image]

3-> Connect to this remote database using the public IPv4 address of the node(EC2 Instance).

**HostAddress:** IPv4 address of the node ec2 instance.

**Port:** 31000